# If-statement dont get true, but it should

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I dont understand why the the first (same for other ones) `if` in sendMessage never gets true. The reciever String is exactly what it should be to be true?!

When i run this and press **send to Alice** I get 3 Toast:

1. Send to Alice (=value of reciever)
2. *[a blank toast]* (=value of phoneNumber)
3. You have to choose a message (=nevermind this!)

   ```
   public void onSend(View src){
   Button b = (Button)src;

   sendMessage(b.getText().toString());

   }

   public void sendMessage(String reciever){

   String phoneNumber = "";
   Toast.makeText(this, reciever, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   if (reciever == "Send to Alice"){
       phoneNumber = "01230340645";
       Toast.makeText(this, "hej", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   else if (reciever == "Send to Bob"){
       phoneNumber = "020312039";
   }

   else if (reciever == "Send to John"){
       phoneNumber = "0102308013";
   }

   Toast.makeText(this, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   if (_message == ""){
       Toast.makeText(this, "You have to choose a message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else {
       Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
       sms.putExtra("sms_body", _message);
       startActivity(sms);
       _message = "";
   }

    }
   ```

Comment: Because you are comparing strings using `==`, which will return you `false`. Use `equals` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare Strings in Java.  Use the equals method.

```
if (reciever.equals("Send to Alice"))...
```

The `==` operator compares references for equality, not the objects those references point to.

Answer (score 5):

try this....

**From:**

```
if (reciever == "Send to Alice")
```

**To:**

```
if (receiver.equals("Send to Alice"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (receiver.equals("Send to Alice"))
```

if that "Send to Alice" is to be checked with case sensitivity and

```
if (receiver.equalsIgnoreCase("Send to Alice"))
```

if that "Send to Alice" is to be checked without case sensitivity and

because `==` will check only the integers(similar) and for strings `.equals` should be used